# How to user Left join with three tables ?mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
  SELECT bussiness.bussId , count(favourites.userID) as fav
              from `bussiness` 
LEFT JOIN `favourites` on (`bussiness`.`bussId` = `favourites`.`bussId`)
                  where bussiness.bussId= 12310
```

when I run this query I get fav = 2.

but when I Left join another table ,

```
    SELECT bussiness.bussId , count(favourites.userID) as fav from `bussiness`

 LEFT JOIN `favourites` on (`bussiness`.`bussId` = `favourites`.`bussId`)
     LEFT JOIN `invoices` on (`bussiness`.`bussId` = `invoices`.`bussId`)
     where bussiness.bussId= 12310
```

I get fav = 88 instead of 2

why this happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if there are multiple occurrences of bussId in the hello table causing the number of rows returned to multiply.  Since you were not doing a distinct count of userID, the query was simply counting the number of rows that contain a userID.  If you want to count the number of unique users, you need to use `COUNT DISTINCT`.  Like this:

```
SELECT bussiness.bussId , count(distinct favourites.userID) as fav from `bussiness`

 LEFT JOIN `favourites` on (`bussiness`.`bussId` = `favourites`.`bussId`)
     LEFT JOIN `hello` on (`bussiness`.`bussId` = `hello`.`bussId`)
     where bussiness.bussId= 12310
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, so does mysql also join hello table with favourites table ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Yes, mysql is joining the favourites table to the hello table.

Comment: but why? I thought that mysql will join the business table and favourites, then it will join the hello table with bussiness !

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  You are joining the business table to the hello table.

Comment: Ok, so why I got fav = 88 ? when I join bussiness table with the hello table

Comment: You must have multiple records in the hello table with the same bussIds.

Comment: Yes that's right, I know that, but How the records at hello table, added to the favourite table ?

Comment: It look like for bussId 12310, there are 2 records in the favourite table.  There are 44 records in the hello table for that bussId.  So you are getting 2 x 44 = 88 records.

Comment: Count DISTINCT will count only unique user IDs.  You may need to update your question with more context if this isn't answering your question.